# When to run injectEndpoint

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm using RTK Query to download data, and then that data is manipulated locally, without making any api mutations. So I've done this using `extraReducers`

### `api.js`

```js
const baseApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "baseApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: Globals.BASE_URL + "/api",
    prepareHeaders,
  }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});

export default baseApi;
```

### `draftables.js`

```js
export const { useGetDraftablesQuery } = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: build => ({
    getDraftables: build.query({
      query: ({ draftgroupId, gameTypeId }) => "whatever/url",
      transformResponse: ({ data: players }) =>
        players.map(transformApiPlayer),
    }),
  }),
});
```

### `currentDraftSlice.js`

```js
const currentDraftSlice = createSlice({
  name: "currentDraft",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      baseApi.endpoints.getDraftables.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        state.players = action.payload.map(p => ({
          ...p,
          drafted: false,
        }));
      }
    );
  },
// ... rest of the slice
```

However, the app crashes saying can't get `matchFulfilled` from undefined. Or something like that. This appears to be happening because `createSlice` is being run after `createApi` but *before* `injectEndpoints`.

I've solved this by importing the injection in the slice file:

```
import "../../../services/api/draftables"; // inject draftables endpoint
```

But that just doesn't feel right, it's definitely not centralized.

Is there a solution, or at least a best practice, for this?

*By the way I do understand that fetching data and manipulating it locally is not the intended use case for RTK query, but this is the way I want to use it. The API layer abstraction is too good to give up.*

Answer (score 1):

Import the "injected" api so you can be sure that it is always there - that's how it is meant to be used:

```js
export const apiWithGetDraftables = baseApi.injectEndpoints({ ... })

export const { useGetDraftablesQuery } = apiWithGetDraftables
```

```js
builder.addMatcher(
      apiWithGetDraftables.endpoints.getDraftables.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
```

Of course you can also just export the endpoint or the "guaranteed injected endpoints" - the important part is just that you import it from this file:

```js
export const endpointsWithGetDraftables = apiWithGetDraftables.endpoints

export const getDraftablesEndpoint = apiWithGetDraftables.endpoints.getDraftables
```